# Comparator - thenComparing() method produces 'no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that Object conforms to Comparable<? super U>'

Tags: java, java-stream, comparator

What is a proper usage of the Comparator's method`thenComparing()` and why it's not working properly in my code? I don't quite understand the reason of the error I'm getting:

```
no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so 
that Object conforms to Comparable<? super U>
```

That is the code that produces the error:

```
Map<Integer, Long> sortedCards = new LinkedHashMap<>();
List<Card> cards = // initializing the list

cards.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        card -> card.kind.rank,
        Collectors.counting()
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                     .thenComparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
    .forEachOrdered(e -> sortedCards.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

My `Card` class:

```
public static class Card implements Comparable<Card> {

    private Kind kind;
    
    // constructors, getters, etc.
}
```

`Kind` enum:

```
public enum Kind {

    TWO(1, "2"), THREE(2, "3"), FOUR(3, "4"), // etc.;
    
    public int rank;
    // constructors, getters, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the compilation error you've encountered is a type inference issue.

The when you're chaining methods while constructing a comparator, the compiler fails to infer the type of the method reference from the target type.

You can resolve it by using *type-witness*, i.e. providing the types of *key* and *value* explosively in the angle brackets `<K,V>` (these are the types declared by `comparingByValue()` which produces the first comparator in the chain):

```
Map.Entry.<Integer, Long>comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())
    .thenComparing(Map.Entry::getKey)
```

Also, instead of `forEachOrdered()` it would be better to use `collect()` and generate a `Map` as a result of the stream execution then populate pre-created map via *side-effects*. It makes your code more verbose and less expressive because you need to instantiate the resulting collection separately, and goes against the guidelines listed in the documentation.

Methods `forEach()` and `forEachOrdered()` exist as a last resort, and it's **discouraged** to use them as a substitution of reduction operations like `collect()` or `reduce()`, for more information refer to the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects), pay attention to the code examples.

That's how it would look like if we make use of `collect()`:

```
Map<Integer, Long> sortedCards = cards.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(card -> card.kind.rank, Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Long>comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .thenComparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        (left, right) -> {
            throw new AssertionError("duplicate keys are not expected");
        },
        LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
```

Comment: @Magda You mean to make the ordering by *key* to be *descending*? You can use another flavor of [`thenComparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing(java.util.function.Function,java.util.Comparator)) which expects  *function* + *comparator* `.thenComparing(Map.Entry::getKey, Comparator.reverseOrder()))`